# Web Page doesn't load when data is being received from Xbee

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, ethernet, xbee

I have an Arduino Mega I am using as a simple web server. Right now the web page is two simple lines of text. There is an XBee radio attached to the unit to receive data from another unit. However, when the server unit is receiving data the web page will not start up. There's a switch on the shield to switch it into `Micro` for the radio, or `USB`. If I reset, or power on, the server unit with the switch in `USB` mode it loads fine; then once the web page loads I can flip it on `Micro` and it will refresh fine even while receiving data. However, if I try to power on the unit, or reset the unit, with the switch on `Micro` it will not load the web page. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Schematic:

Server Unit: Ethernet shield with HanRun HR911105A 13/15 ethernet jac placed on Mega ADK. There is a Wireless Proto Shield with XBee Pro 538 radio placed on the ethernet shield.

Remote Unit: There is a Wireless Proto Shield with XBee Pro 538 radio placed on the Mega ADK.

`setup()`:

```cpp
void setup() {
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:    
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);//, gateway, mask);
    server.begin();
}
```

`loop()`:

```cpp
void loop() {
    // Listen for incoming clients 
    client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
        if (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();

            // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
            // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
            // so you can send a reply
            if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {

                // Send a standard http response header
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
                client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
                client.println();
                client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
                client.println("<html>");

                client.println("<br>");
                client.println("<BODY BGCOLOR=powderblue>");
                client.println("<center>");
                client.println("<b>My WebPage</b>");
                client.println("<br>");
                client.println("<b>Web Server and Radio Receiver </b>");
                client.println("<br>");
                client.println("version November 30, 2016");
                client.println("<br>");
                client.println("</center>");
                client.println("</body>");
                client.println("</html>");

                break;

            }
            if (c == '\n') {
                // you're starting a new line
                currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } else if (c != '\r') {
                // you've gotten a character on the current line
                currentLineIsBlank = false;
            } 
        }
    }
}
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);
// close the connection:
client.stop();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the schematic and both `setup()` and `loop()` functions that will manage both `Micro` and 'USB` links ?

Comment: @J.Piquard I just posted my Arduino set up, as well as the code.

Comment: In your source code, close to the example `WebServer.ino`, you have assigned in `loop()` the `client = server.available();` with certainly `EthernetClient client` declared before `setup()` meaning that another client has been created before. Try to declare `EthernetClient client = server.available();` inside the `loop()`.

Comment: @J.Piquard I tried your suggestion but it unfortunately didn't solve the problem

Comment: @J.Piquard I tried moving `Serial.begin(9600)` to be the last line of `setup()` and now the web page loads when reset while receiving data, but it still won't load while receiving data when first powered on